# Enable logging for redis server on windows

Tags: logging, redis

I am using Redis 2.6.12 on windows, I want to view log of redis operation. I have changed redis.conf file but not getting log. I have used following properties in file.

```
loglevel debug

logfile redisfile.log
```

Please help me to enable loging for redis server